# What does RewriteRule ^Customer(|/.*)$ Customer.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] mean in my .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not sure what **RewriteRule ^Customer(|/.*)$ Customer.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]** actually mean.
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`QSA` means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite.

`L` means if the rule matches,  it wont process any more RewriteRules below this one.

So `yourdomain.com/Customer/123?var=foo` will be rewritten to `yourdomain.com/Customer.php?q=123&var=foo`